# MySQL Multiple JOIN query

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables:

Table A:

- id int
- value varchar

Table B:

- id int
- a_id default null

Table C:

- id int
- a_id not null

And I need to group number of B rows and C rows by A.value:

```
+---------+----------------------+----------------------+
| A.value | COUNT(DISTINCT B.id) | COUNT(DISTINCT C.id) |
+---------+----------------------+----------------------+
| NULL    | 100                  | 0                    |
| 1       | 543                  | 324                  |
...
```

The problem is that the B table has a nullable foreign key while C.a_id can not be null. 
So after hour of trying I can't get the right query. Either C.a_id are losing or B.a_id.

What is the right way to get it?

Comment: I tried RIGHT JOIN B which retrieved first two columns. But the next join on C ruins everything because C can have a_id that are missing from B

Comment: On which element do you join the C table ? (the B.a_id or A.id)

Answer (score 0):

Because the values are pretty large, it might be better to do the calculations in subqueries:

```
select a.name, Distinct_B, Distinct_C
from (select distinct a.name from TableA a) a left outer join
     (select a.value, count(distinct b.id) as Distinct_B
      from TableA a join
           TableB b
           on a.id = b.a_id
      group by a.value
     ) b
     on a.value = b.value left outer join
     (select a.value, count(distinct c.id) as distinct_C
      from TableA a join
           TableC c
           on a.id = c.a_id
    ) c
    on a.value = c.value
```

This looks more complicated, but it does not require a partial cartesian product within each a.value.  Also, it can be simplified, if there are no multiple a.values allowed.

If you want to keep all B values that have "NULL" a_id by assigning them a NULL a.value, then use this subquery instead:

```
select a.value, sum(Distinct_B), sum(Distinct_C)
from ((select distinct a.name, 0 as Distinct_B, 0 as Distinct_C
       from TableA a
      ) union all
      (select a.value, count(distinct b.id) as Distinct_B, 0 as Distinct_C
       from TableB b left outer join
            TableA a
            on a.id = b.a_id
       group by a.value
      ) union all
      (select a.value, 0 as Distinct_B, count(distinct c.id) as distinct_C
       from TableC c left outer join
            TableA a 
           on a.id = c.a_id
      )
     ) t
```

group by a.value

This uses aggregation instead of a join to bring the values together.

Comment: It's seems that this subquery doesn't help with loosing null values. (Probably because of the left outer join?)

Comment: @ziguratahmir . . . Those nefarious NULLs.  I fixed the query to a version that will work.